# How to run bash file in Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, dockerfile, containers

Im trying to execute bash file called start.bash by CMD["bash" ,"start.bash"] in Dockerfile. When I create the image this command is not executed for some reason even though the bash file was of course copied properly in the dockerfile.
The point is that while im trying to run this command inside the container itself its success.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# build back end
FROM node:12.22.12 AS server_build

###ENV HOSTNAME myhost

WORKDIR /VideoServiceApp

COPY ./projConf.json /VideoServiceApp
COPY ./projVideoApp.json /VideoServiceApp
COPY ./front/UIVideo ./front/UIVideo
COPY ./front/videoService ./front/videoService
COPY --from=client_build /VideoServiceApp/front/video/dist/video /VideoServiceApp/front/video/dist/video
COPY ./start.bash /VideoServiceApp
COPY ./classes ./classes

WORKDIR /VideoServiceApp/front/UIVideo
RUN npm install

WORKDIR /VideoServiceApp/front/videoService
RUN npm install && npm install -g typescript@latest
RUN tsc

EXPOSE 7717 7708

WORKDIR /VideoServiceApp
CMD ["bash" , "start.bash"]
```

Comment: How did you run the docker image ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full path for the command when you are using the CMD array's syntax.

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "start.bash"]
```

You could also switch to the shell form of `CMD`

```
CMD bash start.bash
```

For more information read the [CMD-Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Comment: It still does not work ... in the same folder inside the container where I placed start.bash I do not have a bin ..
I do not understand why when I run the command from inside the container it works but from the outside the same command in the same position does not work ...

Comment: I think you most likely want to use `ENTRYPOINT` or `RUN` instead of `CMD`. `CMD` does not get executed if you run a container and create a shell with with `docker run -it <Container> bash`.